# How to align right, sections of a rootElement in a DialogViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I'm writing some codes for iOS using c# in Xamarin Studio. In a dialogViewController , I'm creating a rootElement that has several Sections.How can I Align Right ,Caption and Elements of a Section. I'm creating the rootElement like this:

```
 RootElement  CreateRootElement ()
{       
  return new RootElement ("RootElement") 
  {
  new Section ("Caption1") {
    (createFirstElement ())
    },
  new Section ("Caption2")) {
    (createSecondElement ())
    }
  };
}

List<Element> createFirstElement ()
{
 List<Element> myList;
 //fill this list
 return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a right aligned section caption by using the Section initializer 'public Section(UIView header)' with the following method:

```
private UILabel LabelForSection(string title) {
    RectangleF frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 22);
    UILabel label = new UILabel(frame);
    label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
    label.Text = "Caption1";
    return label;
}
```

And then initialize your section like so:

```
new Section(LabelForSection("Caption1"))
```

Can you give an example of what you mean when you say:

> How can I Align Right Elements of a Section?